# Number of possible combination of n objects in k groups with various caveats

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

I'm trying to figure out how the possible combinations of n objects in k groups. However there are the following constraints:

I only need the results for k=1,2 at present but this is liable to change, a general approach/formula would be highly appreciated.

1. The size of the groups does not matter as long as the sum of all the elements in all the groups is
   less than or equal to n-1.
2. Empty groups are not allowed
3. An element can exist in all k groups simultaneously (this is the real issue I'm having)
4. If we had k=2 and n=6 then the groups {1,2} {3,4,5} are the same as {3,4,5} {1,2}.
5. A group cannot have repeating elements (all elements are distinct)

I don't think I've left anything out, let me know if I am in anyway unclear

Kind regards

Comment: Do I understand correctly that some elements may be not present in any group, and at least one element must be not present in any group? I see that your example contradicts this understanding but I do not see that it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: !) Yes, some elements may not be present in any group. 2) At least one element will not be present in any of the groups. I changed the example in the question as you correctly pointed out it contradicts my criteria. n = 6, k = 3 could be {1,2} {2,5,2} {3,1} for example.

Comment: The order of elements in a group does not matter, does it?

Comment: Group {1,2} = {2,1}. So n=6, k=2: {1,2} {3,4,5} is the same as {2,1} {4,3,5} and therefore I only need to include 1 of these 2 potential outcomes else I will be double counting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the solution $N(n,k)$ for the case $k=2$ will be given, since the general problem is hardly tractable in view of simultaneous conditions 3 and 4.

The number in question is:
$$
N(n,2)=\frac12\left[\sum_{j_1=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j_2=1}^{n-1-j_1}\binom n{j_1}\binom n{j_2}+
\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}\binom n{j}\right].
$$
The first values for $n=1\dots10$ are:
$$
0,0,6,34,170,741,3143,12958,52998,215125.
$$

Explanation: we choose two non-empty subsets of the set consisting of $n$ elements (one for the first and one for the second group). As the groups are assumed to be identical we count any choice of two subsets twice (with interchanged order of the groups) except for those with two identical subsets which are counted only once. Therefore we add the number of the latter to the double sum and divide the result by 2.

Comment: Ah so no general form can be found due to conditions 3 and conditions 4. Wow thanks a lot, this was not an easy problem for me at least and I applaud the effort research. Thank you ever so much

Comment: Apparently I'm not able to give you a reputation point that can be seen by the public

Comment: That's no problem. Most important is your feedback.